# Python function program and it's output with reason

Tags: python

```
def printmessage(message, ntimes = 1):
      print(message * ntimes)
printmessage(“Hello”)
printmessage(“Hello”, 5)
```

i see the correct output of the program is but i want the reason :

```
Hello
HelloHelloHelloHelloHello
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What is it you don't understand? Please be specific, see [ask]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what confuses you? What did you expect the output to be and how does the correct output differ from what you're expecting?

Comment: `ntimes` is a default parameter. If the function is called without the argument, the argument gets its default value.

Comment: when you multiply a string by a number, it creates a string that contains number copies of the original string

Comment: print(message * ntimes) . in this step i thought it was trying to multiply string and number, may be i'm wrong as i'm pretty much beginners.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin can you please elaborate the line 'it creates a string that contains number copies of the original string'

Answer (score 1):

At the first time, the function is called with no arguments. So it uses the default argument value. So 'Hello' printed 1 time.

```
printmessage(“Hello”)
```

At the second time, since an argument value is given it overrides the default argument value i.e., 5. So the word 'Hello' gets printed 5 times.

```
printmessage(“Hello”, 5)
```

Also, when you multiply a string with a number `(string * 5)`, it will get printed that many times.